# How to show the vector<Point2f> as a image?

Tags: c++, opencv

I just start to learn opencv, I have defined a vector like:

```
vector<Point2f> cornersB;
```

and after that i have done some calculations like:goodFeaturesToTrack,cornerSubPix and calcOpticalFlowPyrLK using cornersB.

And now I want to show cornerB to see the points that has been drawn, my code is:

```
pointmat = Mat(cornersB);
imshow("Window", pointmat);
```

But I got error said that bad number of channels (Source image must have 1, 3 or 4 channels) in cvConvertImage.

Anyone can teach me how to show the points of cornerB in an image?
I just want to see the points (points in white and the background in black).

Comment: loop over vector and draw a small circle for each point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simpler is to use cv::drawKeypoints

```
drawKeypoints( InputArray image, const std::vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, InputOutputArray outImage,const Scalar& color=Scalar::all(-1), int flags=DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT );
```

In your case, let define a black image as image:

```
cv::Mat image(512,512,CV_8U)
image.setTo(0);
```

Then convert cornersB to cv::KeyPoint kp_cornerB and define the color as white with CV_RGB(255, 255, 255)

```
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> kp_cornerB ;
// TODO convert cornersB to kp_cornerB
cv::Mat pointmat;
cv::drawKeypoints(image, kp_cornerB, pointmat, CV_RGB(255, 255, 255));
imshow("Window", pointmat);
```

The conversion can be done with a for loop on the vector:

```
for(vector<Point2f>::const_iterator it = cornersB.begin();
        it != cornersB.end(); it++) {
    cv::KeyPoint kp(*it, 8);
    kp_cornerB.push_back(kp);
}
```

Here, the value '8' is the 'size' of the keypoint.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your perfect comment, but when i change the 8 in cv::KeyPoint kp(*it, 8); to other numbers, why the size of the keypoint doesn't change? looking forward to your reply.

Comment: When you write "the size of the keypoint doesn't change" I guess you mean when you display it ? If you want a possible change, you must add a fourth option to drawKeypoints corresponding to flag DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS. In pratice: 

cv::drawKeypoints(image, kp_cornerB, pointmat, CV_RGB(255, 255, 255),4);

Comment: okay! solved! one more question is i don't want the points keep adding on the image, so i need to clear kp_cornerB after one loop, how should i do that? (how to clear a keypoint vector)

Comment: Hi @WilburHe if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.